# Three.js How to dynamically change a SplineCurve3

Tags: three.js

I would like to update the points of a SplineCurve3 and put and move objects along its path. 
At the moment I create a new spline every time I change one of its points. Afterwards I use .getPoint(i) to rearrange all the objects. It works, but it doesn't feel very efficient.

Is it possible to update an existing spline? Is it possible to directly access the interpolated points? Or should I use a totally different approach? I just started using three.js today, so maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Thanks,
Armin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can just change the `points` member of `SplineCurve3` without creating a new `SplineCurve3`; see http://jsfiddle.net/epjfczz8/ . You'll still need to update the position of all your objects though---probably no way around that.

I'm not sure what you mean by "directly access the interpolated points," but maybe looking at the source for [`THREE.Curve`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/core/Curve.js) would help? It's pretty straightforward to follow.

Comment: For some reason I thought SplineCurve3 administers an internal array of interpolated points for drawing purposes - which is not the case. So basically I just change the "knots" of my spline (mySpline.points[i].set(x,y,z)) and update my geometry and mesh afterwards by using getPoints… Thanks for the hints!